# Работа со строками. Ошибка с удалением элемента двумерного массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Выполняя задачу: Задано предложение. Составить программу, которая определяет и выводит на экран все его слова, предварительно преобразовав каждое слово по следующему правилу:

1. заменить первую встреченную букву «a» на «о»;
2. удалить из слова все вхождения последней буквы (кроме него самого),
3. оставить в слове только первые вхождения каждой буквы (остальные удалить)
4. в самом длинном слове удалить среднюю (средние) буквы (принять, что такое слово есть одним)
   столкнулся с ошибкой: `'str' object doesn't support item deletion.

Как мне по-другому можно это реализовать?

Код:

```
sentence=[str(i) for i in input().split()]

last=''

for i in range(0, len(sentence)):
    sentence[i]=sentence[i].replace('а', 'о', 1) 
print(*sentence)

for i in range(0, len(sentence)):
    for j in range(0, len(sentence[i])-1):
        if sentence[i][j]==sentence[i][(len(sentence[i]))-1]:
            del(sentence[i][j])
        else:
            continue
     
print(*sentence)
```

Comment: строки есть неизменяемый тип данных в питоне.и нельзя удалить букву из строки. покажите значене sentence перед удалением.

Comment: Преобразуйте строку в список, например: `items = list(sentence[i])`, теперь вы можете менять список, после того как закончите обработку списка сделайте его снова строкой: `sentence[i] = ''.join(items)`. Или заранее сделайте и вправду двухмерный массив (в коде у вас список строк), через такой код: `sentence=[list(i) for i in input().split()]`. *Кст*, в `for i in input().split()` переменная `i` и так строка, поэтому нет смысла вызывать для нее `str` :)